# How can I move a string with calculations and brackets according to PEP8

Tags: python, pep8

I have

```
spent_calories = ((cc1 * self.weight + (mean_speed * 2.0 // self.height) * cc2 * self.weight) * self.duration * H_IN_M)
```

and I need to translate part of the expression but a new line. I tried to wrap everything in parentheses and started transferring, but then there was a difficulty with indentation. How can I do it?

Comment: Why not break apart? Like `mean_speed * 2.0 // self.height` on its own variable / line, etc. What exactly were your difficulties?

Comment: yes, I understand that it was possible to put it on variables, but I wanted to divide it right away

Comment: Okay, but what specific error are you getting?

Comment: When I move it to the next line, where it starts with a sign, it gives an error 'continuation line under-indented for visual indent'

Comment: As it says, "under indented", so indent it further

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick read about the topic. https://www.pythonmorsels.com/breaking-long-lines-code-python/

Many people used to break long lines using a backslash `\` but it's not recommended according to PEP8.

```
# Don't do this
a_very_long_variable_definition = another_quite_lengthy_variable_name +\
    something // other % 12
```

Instead use parenthesis `()`, brackets `[]` or braces `{}` to indicate that your line is not done yet. Indentation is usually set to +1 level from the start or visually indented to match an element logically like the function call example below.

```
a_very_long_variable_definition = (another_quite_lengthy_variable_name +
    something // other % 12)

my_supercool_function(someone + dumped - a_huge_amount / of ** clutter +
                      here - but_it_wasnt_me)
```

Of course in the end a lot of the long lines can be avoided by structuring the code and variables better but it's not always possible. Line length limitation is a rule you can agree upon with the developing team, I for example prefer using 120 characters.

For your snippet, this formatting is fine:

```
spent_calories = ((cc1 * self.weight + (mean_speed * 2.0 // self.height) * 
    cc2 * self.weight) * self.duration * H_IN_M)
```